# Issue when inputting from a file using BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, layout, input, bufferedreader

I've been trying to import the properties of several chemical elements from a text file I've made using BufferedReader. I intend to save each property as a variable then create an array of objects for each elements with its associated properties.

My code looks like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
      ElementsTest[] element = new ElementsTest[118];

      try {
           File file = new File("Elements.txt");
           reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

           for (int counter = 0 ; counter < 118 ; counter++)
           {
                String name = reader.readLine();
                int atomicNum = counter + 1;
                String atomicWeight = reader.readLine();
                String elementSymbol = reader.readLine();
                String elementCharge = reader.readLine();
                String fullElectronConfig = reader.readLine();
                String shortElectronConfig = reader.readLine();
                String elementState = reader.readLine();
                String elementType = reader.readLine();
                String density = reader.readLine();
                String meltingPoint = reader.readLine();
                String boilingPoint = reader.readLine();
                String emptyLine = reader.readLine();

                element[counter] = new ElementsTest (name, atomicNum,  atomicWeight, elementSymbol, elementCharge, fullElectronConfig, shortElectronConfig, elementState, elementType, density, meltingPoint, boilingPoint);
           }
```

And here is what the text file looks like (a small excerpt from the 118 total elements):

```
Hydrogen
1.008
H
+1
1s^1
N/A
Gas
Non-Metal
0.08988
-259.16
-252.879

Helium
4.003
He
0
1s2
N/A
Gas
Noble Gas
0.1786
−272.20
−268.928

Lithium
6.941
He
+1
N/A
[He] 2s1
Solid
Alkali Metal
0.534
180.50
1330

Beryllium
9.012
Be
+2
N/A
[He] 2s2
Solid
Alkaline Earth Metal
1.85
1287
2970
```

The program compiles and runs, but I get an incorrect output (I coded the buttons to have their text set to the elementSymbol of the object, instead I get a plethora of properties).

[image]

Here is the remainder of my GUI code if that helps at all:

```
JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[118];
      for (int i = 0 ; i < 118 ; i++)
      {
           buttonArray[i] = new JButton();
           buttonArray[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
      }

      for (int counter2 = 0 ; counter2 < 118 ; counter2++)
      {
           String currentSymbol = element[counter2].getElementSymbol();
           buttonArray[counter2].setText(currentSymbol);

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Metal"))
           {
               buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
               buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
               buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Non-Metal"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Noble Gas"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.PINK);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Transition Metal"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Lanthanide"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Alkali Metal"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.RED);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Alkaline Earth Metal"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Halogen"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Metalloid"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           if (element[counter2].getElementType().equals("Actinide"))
           {
                buttonArray[counter2].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
                buttonArray[counter2].setBorderPainted(false);
           }

           else {
                buttonArray[counter2].setOpaque(true);
           }
      }

      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[0]);
      metalsPanel.add(new JButton(""));
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[2]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[3]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[10]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[11]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[18]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[19]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[36]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[37]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[54]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[55]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[86]);
      metalsPanel.add(buttonArray[87]);

      for (int x = 20 ; x < 30 ; x++)
      {
           transitionMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 38 ; x < 48 ; x++)
      {
           transitionMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      transitionMetalsPanel.add(new JButton("57-71"));

      for (int x = 71 ; x < 80 ; x++)
      {
           transitionMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      transitionMetalsPanel.add(new JButton("89-103"));

      for (int x = 103 ; x < 112 ; x++)
      {
           transitionMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      nonMetalsPanel.add(new JButton(""));
      nonMetalsPanel.add(new JButton(""));
      nonMetalsPanel.add(new JButton(""));
      nonMetalsPanel.add(new JButton(""));
      nonMetalsPanel.add(new JButton(""));
      nonMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[1]);

      for (int x = 4 ; x < 10 ; x++)
      {
           nonMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 12 ; x < 18 ; x++)
      {
           nonMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 30 ; x < 36 ; x++)
      {
           nonMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 48 ; x < 54 ; x++)
      {
           nonMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 80 ; x < 86 ; x++)
      {
           nonMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 112 ; x < 118 ; x++)
      {
           nonMetalsPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 56 ; x < 71 ; x++)
      {
           lanthanidesPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      for (int x = 88 ; x < 103 ; x++)
      {
           lanthanidesPanel.add(buttonArray[x]);
      }

      window.setVisible (true);
      window.pack();
 }
```

And here is the ElementsTest class which contains the retrieval methods for its properties:

```
public class ElementsTest extends Object
{
 private String name;
 private int atomicNum;
 private String atomicWeight;
 private String elementSymbol;
 private String elementCharge;
 private String fullElectronConfig;
 private String shortElectronConfig;
 private String elementState;
 private String elementType;
 private String density;
 private String meltingPoint;
 private String boilingPoint;

public ElementsTest (String name, int atomicNum, String atomicWeight, String     elementSymbol, String elementCharge, String fullElectronConfig, String shortElectronConfig, String elementState, String elementType, String density, String meltingPoint, String boilingPoint)
 {
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.atomicNum = atomicNum;
      this.atomicWeight = atomicWeight;
      this.elementSymbol = elementSymbol;
      this.elementCharge = elementCharge;
      this.fullElectronConfig = fullElectronConfig;
      this.shortElectronConfig = shortElectronConfig;
      this.elementState = elementState;
      this.elementType = elementType;
      this.density = density;
      this.meltingPoint = meltingPoint;
      this.boilingPoint = boilingPoint;

 }

 public String getName()
 {
      return this.name;
 }

 public String getAtomicWeight()
 {
      return this.atomicWeight;
 }

 public String getElementSymbol()
 {
      return this.elementSymbol;
 }

 public String getElementCharge()
 {
      return this.elementCharge;
 }

 public String getFullElectronConfig()
 {
      return this.fullElectronConfig;
 }

 public String getShortElectronConfig()
 {
      return this.shortElectronConfig;
 }

 public String getElementState()
 {
      return this.elementState;
 }

 public String getElementType()
 {
      return this.elementType;
 }

 public String getDensity()
 {
      return this.density;
 }

 public String getMeltingPoint()
 {
      return this.meltingPoint;
 }

 public String getBoilingPoint()
 {
      return this.boilingPoint;
 }
```

}

I've gone over my text file several times but I cant seem to find where the input could be going wrong QQ Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Code or output that forms part of a question should be posted in the question, not as an external link. Otherwise the question has zero permanent value and is liable for deletion.

Comment: I tried posting the image directly in the question but it says I don't have the reputation for it. Any way to get the image into my post without directly showing it or breaking the rules?

Comment: No idea, but the image doesn't tell us anything useful anyway. There's no evidence here that a file is being misread. It's more likely that there is something wrong with your *GUI* code, which you haven't posted.

Comment: Perhaps you could verify @EJP's hypothesis by inserting `println()` statements on those lines you read in. Feel free to share those too.

Comment: I've removed the image and added all the GUI code that comes after the code I gave before. Hopefully that helps. I'll do the println() verification in a few and post back with my findings.

Comment: Leave the image. To respectfully disagree with @EJP, I'm not convinced there's nothing useful there.

Comment: Can you add ElementsTest code

Comment: I added the code for ElementsTest

Comment: From what i've been seeing, there are no errors in the file input. I can't seem to find anything in the ElementsTest code either. Could the error be hidden somewhere in my GUI code?